# Can a javascript function be a class and an instance of another object?

Tags: javascript, mean.io

If you look at this code:

```
    function supportAggregate(Meanio) {

      Meanio.prototype.aggregated = function(ext, group, callback) {
        // Aggregated Data already exists and is ready
        if (Meanio.Singleton.config.clean.aggregate === false){
          return callback('');
        }
        if (aggregated[group][ext].data) return callback(aggregated[group][ext].data);

        // No aggregated data exists so we will build it
        sortAggregateAssetsByWeight();

        // Returning rebuild data. All from memory so no callback required
        callback(aggregated[group][ext].data);
      };

      Meanio.prototype.aggregatedsrc = function(ext, group, callback) {
        // Aggregated Data already exists and is ready
        if (Meanio.Singleton.config.clean.aggregate !== false){
          if(ext==='js'){
            if(group==='header'){
              return callback(['/modules/aggregated.js?group=header']);
            }else{
              return callback(['/modules/aggregated.js']);
            }
          }else if(ext==='css' && group==='header'){
            return callback(['/modules/aggregated.css']);
          }
          return callback([]);
        }
        if (aggregated[group][ext].src) return callback(aggregated[group][ext].src);

        // No aggregated data exists so we will build it
        sortAggregateAssetsByWeight();

        // Returning rebuild data. All from memory so no callback required
        callback(aggregated[group][ext].src);
      };

      // Allows rebuilding aggregated data
      Meanio.prototype.rebuildAggregated = function() {
        sortAggregateAssetsByWeight();
      };

      Meanio.prototype.Module.prototype.aggregateAsset = function(type, asset, options) {
        options = options || {};
        if (!options.inline && !options.absolute && !options.url) {
          asset = path.join(Meanio.modules[this.name].source, this.name, 'public/assets', type, asset);
        }
        Meanio.aggregate(type, asset, options, Meanio.Singleton.config.clean);
      };

      Meanio.onModulesFoundAggregate = function(ext, options) {
        var config = Meanio.Singleton.config.clean;
        var aggregator = new Aggregator(options, false, config);
        for (var name in Meanio.modules) {
          aggregator.readFiles(ext, path.join(process.cwd(), Meanio.modules[name].source, name.toLowerCase(), 'public'));
        }
      };

      Meanio.aggregate = function(ext, asset, options, config) {
        var aggregator;
        options = options || {};
        if (!asset) {
          return;
        }
        aggregator = new Aggregator(options, true, config);
        if (options.inline) return aggregator.addInlineCode(ext, asset);
        else if (options.url) return aggregator.getRemoteCode(ext, asset);
        else if (options.singlefile) return aggregator.processDirOfFile(ext, asset);
        else return aggregator.readFile(ext, path.join(process.cwd(), asset));
      };

      Meanio.prototype.aggregate = Meanio.aggregate;
    }

    module.exports = supportAggregate;
```

(https://github.com/linnovate/meanio/blob/master/lib/aggregation.js#L213)

You can see that there are two types of functions for Meanio that are created. Also, by the way, you can see where this is instantiated here: https://github.com/linnovate/meanio/blob/master/lib/mean.js#L114

But I'm just confused. Sometime, Meanio functions are defined like this:

```
Meanio.prototype.myfunction = function() {}
```

and sometimes they are defined like this:

```
Meanio.myfunction = function() {}
```

I just don't get it; although I have a feeling that dependency injection is somehow involved.

How can this be? How can an object be both a class and an instance of itself?

This code is very confusing to me, and I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this for me. I'm not asking you to heavily research the code, but if you could give me a general understanding, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a function can have properties as well as a prototype. The properties will be accessible directly on the function, but not on instances of the function(class, constructor, whatever).

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes, so applying rules from other programming languages that do have them is bound to cause confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can an object be both a class and an instance of itself?

That's not what's going on here. The object passed to the function is an instance.

The function does however modify both the instance that you pass to it, and the class of that instance.

If you create two instances of the same class, and pass one of them to the function, the other instance is not modified, but the class that is common to them is modified. Example:

```
function MyClass() {}

var a = new MyClass();
var b = new MyClass();

supportAggregate(a);
```

Now both `a.rebuildAggregated` and `b.rebuildAggregated` exist, as that is added to the class. The `a.onModulesFoundAggregate` exists because it's added to the instance, but `b.onModulesFoundAggregate` doesn't exist.

(Note: The example won't actually work, as there is more going on. The class has to have some more properties to work with that function, the example is only to show the difference between properties added to the prototype and to the instance.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a constructor

```
// First I will define a constructor
function MyClass() {
   this.classproperty = 1;
}
```

In Javascript the constructor is also an object instance. When I use "this" keyword inside a constructor I'm telling that I want to create a new property inside a special object present in all javascript objects called prototype.

```
// Then I add a new property without using prototype obj
MyClass.newProperty = 2;

alert(MyClass.classproperty); // alert 1
alert(MyClass.newProperty); // alert 2
                            // It will work because I'm using the MyClass main Object
```

When you create a new instance from Myclass Obj. The new created object will inherit the prototype object from parent (the one used to instantiate), but not the properties added straight to MyClass obj:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
alert(instance.newProperty); // undefined because the new instance will
                             // inherit only what is inside prototype obj
```

I have to add it to the prototype object in order to new instances inherit the property;

```
Myclass.prototype.newProperty = 2;
var instance = new Myclass();
alert(instance.newProperty) // alert 2
```